# Gerar arquivo de assinatura digital com delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, assinatura-digital

Consigo listar todos os certificados digitais com o `CAPICOM`, escolher o certificado que quero utilizar na assinatura, obter o arquivo que quero assinar, gerar o `md5` do mesmo, consigo até assinar, porém não consigo gerar um arquivo `P7S` que o seja reconhecido. Como eu poderia fazer isso? Utilizar `OpenSSlUtils.pas` com `TX509Certificate` e `TPKCS7`? Desde já agradeço a todos!

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas.

Comment: Talvez esse link possa lhe ajudar [Documentação P7S](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/ajuda-com-assinatura-digital/456671)

Comment: Porque não deixa esse serviço com a a ACBr ?

Answer (score 0):

Matheus você pode usar essa lib **[Crypt2](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/dd_CkCrypt2Ref.html)** e [nesse site](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/crypt_create_p7s_using_pfx.asp) possui um exemplo de como gerar o arquivo p7s.

Caso não queira usar esta lib é possível fazer o mesmo usando a própria dll do OpenSSL existe este [repositório](https://github.com/Arvur/OpenSSL-Delphi) no github que contém as unit das declarações da OpenSSL e inclusive alguns exemplos de utilização.

Mas comparando o demo do primeiro link é bem tranquilo de implementar com a openssl o mesmo recurso.

Comment: Diego, essa solução ajuda no quesito de certificado A3?